# Passing variables in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I'm trying to run a GraphQL query in the AWS AppSync console:

```
query MyQuery {
  getUserInfoById(id: "1234566789") {
    account {
      id // need this value for getAvailableCourses
    }
  }
  getAvailableCourses(accountId: "", pageNumber: 0) {
    data {
      id
      name
      type
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I need the value `account.id` in `getUserInfoById` for `getAvailableCourses`. I'm obviously new to GraphQL.  How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there can be two ways you can do this.

1. You can handle this in your frontend by getting user's `id`
   from the session info and pass it to the other query.
2. You can also merge these two queries and make it one. You will also have to change the respective fields. Then attach a resolver with `AvailableCourses` and use `$ctx.source.id` in the resolver to get further details. Schema would look something like this

   ```
   type Account {
     id : ID!
     availableCourses: AvailableCourses
     ..
   }

   type AvailableCourses {
     name: String!
     type: String!
     ..
   }

   type Query {
     getUserInfoById(id: ID!): Account
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using the returned fields as inputs for a second query into your datasource is precisely what field resolvers are for. I can't say for sure since I don't know your schema or access patterns but it looks like you need to make available courses a sub field of the user.